# How to find all files full path with name of file in a text file

Tags: powershell

Edit: I need to match a .txt file that inside of it have something like this Linkin Park - What I've Done - Minutes to Midnight
Red Hot Chili Peppers - Can't Stop - By the Way (Deluxe Edition)
And I need the full path of it like this

C:\Music\Red Hot Chili Peppers\By the Way (Deluxe Edition)\Can’t Stop.flac

C:\Music\Linkin Park\Minutes to Midnight\What I’ve Done.flac

Thanks in advance.

Like the title said I’m trying to get all the files fullpath from a text file that have the similar names in it.
This is what I have so far but when I run this it gets the files path that matches but then it prints out all the files path in that directory and all the sub directories, I only need the files that matches from the .text file.
Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance

```
$Trackpath = "C:\Users\J-PLEX SERVER\Documents\My scripts\Qobuz Downloader\tracks.txt"

$Musicpath = "F:\Music Masters"

$Playlistpath = "C:\Users\J PLEXSERVER\Documents\My scripts\Qobuz Downloader\Playlist.m3u8"

foreach($line in [System.IO.File]:: ReadLines( $Trackpath ))
{    
    $line
    Get-ChildItem $Musicpath -Filter $line*.flac -Recurse | ForEach-Object{$_.FullName} | Select-Object| Add-Content $Playlistpath -Force
}
```

Comment: `-Filter "$line*.flac"` and you can remove `Select-Object`

Comment: I did try that and still prints out all the items in the directory, is like the -filter is not respecting that I only want the items in the .text file.

Comment: Then `$Trackpath` is not an absolute, full file path (for all we can see it is undefined), or your textfile contains empty lines

Comment: Oh wow I think you right the text file did have 2 empty lines in it, is there a way that the script can ignore empty lines in the text file? I don’t want to edit all text files that have empty lines in it, again thanks!
I edited when you commented because I noticed it wasn’t showing but check is there now and the text file doesn’t have empty lines, thanks for your help.

Comment: You can read the lines in the file excluding empty or whitespace-only lines using `foreach ($line in (Get-Content -Path $Trackpath | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' })) { ... }` or `foreach ($line in ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($Trackpath) | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' })) { ... }`

Comment: Everything is fine except that the names of the files I have in the text also includes folder keywords and the search in the path is ignoring that and is giving me path of files that have words in the text, example: file name in text is Linkin  Park - what I’ve done  and the results of path is Linkin Park\What I’ve Done.flac and also is givin me The Notorious BIG\Things Done Changed.flac, any fix for this? Thanks

Comment: Theo the code to skip empty lines didn't work is giving this error: The term '...' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: `...` means _the rest of your code_

Comment: Everything is fine except that the names of the files I have in the text also includes folder keywords and the search in the path is ignoring that and is giving me path of files that have words in the text, example: file name in text is Linkin Park - what I’ve done and the results of path is Linkin Park\What I’ve Done.flac and also is givin me The Notorious BIG\Things Done Changed.flac, any fix for this? anyone that can help me with this? I have try everything but I can't get it right. thanks

Comment: Then you need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72631680/edit) and supply examples of the file listing you have in the text file, along with the desired output

Comment: Done, thank you very much for all your help, I’m learning a lot from this site, so please accept my apology if I look like I’m asking to much.